# CSV to JSON with array of sublists with Python

Tags: python, json, csv, entities

Having troubles converting a CSV file to JSON with array of sub-lists.
The CSV contains lists of some categories. Each column represents a list formed by it's rows. the column header is the category identifier. Need to transform it into a JSON of the format below:

```
[
    {
        "category": "Egypt",
        "list": [
            "Cairo",
            "Alexandria"
        ]
    },
    {
        "category": "USA",
        "list": [
            "California",
            "Texas"
        ]
    }
]
```

CSV of form:

```
Egypt , USA
Cairo , California
Alexandria , Texas
.....
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with pandas?

```
import pandas as pd

# Load the data
data = pd.read_csv(filename)

# Reshaping
data_reshaped = pd.melt(df).groupby('variable').agg(list).reset_index().T
data_reshaped.index = ['category','list']

# Convert to json
data_reshaped.to_json()
```

You get:

```
'{"0":{"category":"Egypt","list":["Cairo","Alexandria "]},
  "1":{"category":"USA","list":["California","Texas"]}}'
```

It's not exactly what you want, but it's a start.

Comment: It works somehow, have to figure out how to put each column into a new category and its list.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

str = '''Egypt , USA
Cairo , California
Alexandria , Texas'''

lines = str.split('\n')
lists = []
for line in lines:
  lists.append(line.split(" , "))
my_list = []
my_dict = {}
for j in range(len(lists[0])):
  my_dict["category"] = lists[0][j]
  my_dict["list"] = [lists[i][j] for i in range(1, len(lists))]
  my_list.append(my_dict)
print(json.dumps(my_list))
```

It's basically a list of dictionaries. So you need to make each individual dictionary in a loop and append it to a new list. You can then use `json.dumps()` to get it in json format.

I'm new to answering things so feel free to ask if anything is unclear.